# what are all these features of gcc? (-l -a -etc)

Tags: c, gcc, g++

Can someone tell me in plan and simple terms what some of the more important features and options are for gcc and what they do? I look at the man pages and my head feels like exploding lol.

Comment: I think the man pages are quite clear about the options. And since you already listed a couple (`-l` and `-a`) why don't you just look for those specific options in the man page to see what they do?

Comment: @casablanca: I suspect there'd be some trouble with `-a` because as far as I can tell, it doesn't exist

Comment: Do vice versa: if you have a certain goal, find options that help you in achieving it.  It will keep your head off of exploding.

Comment: @Hasturkun, `-etc` doesn't exist either.... Or it's a 4.5 feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-O flag with a numeric value will tell the compiler which level of optimization to use when compiling

-pedantic will make sure your code is iso compliant

-o To specify the name of the target executable to generate (by default it's a.out)

-Wextra to add additional compiler warnings to -Wall

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read the manual on [gcc options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary), that groups the options in meaningful ways, and includes precise descriptions of same.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html

As others pointed out: If you are running some sort of unix you can usualy just write 'man gcc' (without quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Good question, and it really does have an answer.

#### -Wall

`gcc -Wall ...` will add lots of useful warnings to make C a much safer language to program in.

Regarding the comments, sure, I like `-Wall -Wno-parentheses` and various other variations.

But someone starting out has to, well, *start* somewhere.

Comment: It also adds a lot of useless ones that hide the real problems. I find if I use -Wall I generally need 5-10 -Wno-... options to get rid of the spam.